# about relative homotopy group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

$S(RP^2),S(CP^2)$denote suspension of real and complex projective space.
Then are the first order relative homotopy group $\pi_1(S(RP^2),RP^2),\pi_1(S(CP^2),CP^2) $trivial?Why?

Comment: $\pi_1($ any suspension) is trivial, isn't it ?

Comment: @Nikita Kalinin: Not quite *any* suspension; the space you suspend had better be connected.

Answer (score 6):

To define the relative homotopy groups of a pair $(X, A)$, let $i:A\to X$ be the inclusion, 
and write $F_i$ for its homotopy fiber.  Then 
$$
\pi_n(X, A) = \pi_{n-1}(F_i).
$$
In your examples, the inclusion maps are nullhomotopic, so the homotopy fibers are
$$
\Omega \Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2
\qquad \mathrm{and}
\qquad 
\Omega \Sigma \mathbb{C}P^2 \times \mathbb{C}P^2,
$$
respectively.   Since these spaces are path-connected, the relative homotopy "groups" in question are trivial.

Comment: This seems like overkill to me. Why not just use the long exact sequence of the pair and that $\pi_0(RP^2)$ and $pi_1(S(RP^2))$ are trivial?

Comment: @GregFriedman This is that argument, just phrased differently. (In particular $\Omega \Sigma \mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2$ being connected is equivalent to $\pi_0(\mathbb{R}P^2)$ and $\pi_1(S(RP^2))$ being trivial.)